# DbContext pluralizing table names on accessing db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following controller:

```
private RACentralContext db = new RACentralContext();
private PeopleContext Peopledb = new PeopleContext();        

public ViewResult StartRA()
    {
        var assessor = Peopledb.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == 6);


        StartRiskAssessmentViewModel viewModel = new StartRiskAssessmentViewModel
        {
            RiskAssessment = new RiskAssessment(),
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

When I run the application it gives the following error:

> 'Invalid object name 'dbo.People'

The context class is:

```
public class RACentralContext : DbContext
{

    public RACentralContext()
        : base("name=RACDev")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<RiskAssessment> RiskAssessments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hazard> Hazards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PPE> PPEs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RiskAssessmentPPE> RiskAssessmentPPEs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PeopleExposed> PeopleExposeds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RiskAssessmentPeopleExposed> RiskAssessmentPeopleExposeds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RiskAssessmentHazard> RiskAssessmentHazards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ControlMeasure> ControlMeasures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Severity> Severitys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Likelihood> Likelihoods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AddControlMeasure> AddControlMeasures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubType> SubTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}

public class PeopleContext : DbContext
{
    public PeopleContext()
        : base("name=PeopleContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

}
```

It's trying to access the puralization of the actual table name, how do I stop it doing this and just get it to access dbo.Person not dbo.People?

Comment: Add that `override void OnModelCreating()` to `PeopleContext`...

Comment: Hvaing added that I get this error : The model backing the 'PeopleContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269). Despite running update-database - force. The People context only has one table from that database not all of them that I use in another application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We specify the table name on the model itself

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person { ... }
```

Comment: Now getting this error: The model backing the 'PeopleContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Comment: you need to perform migrations when chainging in model. Look at this http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: You may need to specify the context - try the flag -ConfigurationTypeName